# 2020 Moderator Election - Results

Tags: discussion, election

Music: Practice & Theory's [second moderator election](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Richard]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5741372922396672/0).

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations, Richard! I think we're in good hands.

I humbly concede to my excellent opponent.

Comment: I urge you not to concede. YOU WON THIS ELECTION, BY A LOT.

Comment: I just hope we never lose your music recommendations in chat, luser droog!

Comment: Thanks, not planning on going anywhere anytime soon. Although my free time will probably change in a few months when I'll have to find a full time job.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you, everyone. That makes two elections this week that went the way I'd hoped!

I hope that I can be a positive presence, and thanks especially to luser droog for joining the fray; I have no doubt he would have been a fantastic addition to the team.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't like a recount..?!

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations, Richard, commiserations, luser droog!  Richard, I hope it won't eat into the time and effort you put into your answers, and you get treated with the respect you mods deserve. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what he said ^ :-)